# Como mudar o valor de uma defaultProps em um componente React?

Tags: react

Boa tarde,

Eu tenho um componente de loading que usa uma props default.

```
class Loading extends Component {
  render() {
    const loadingClasses = classNames({
      'loading': this.props.loading,
    })

    return (
      <div className={loadingClasses}>
        {this.props.loading === 'loading-inline' && <i className='fa fa-spinner fa-spin mr2' />}
        <FormattedMessage id='loading' />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Loading.propTypes = {
  loading: PropTypes.string,
}

Loading.defaultProps = {
  loading: 'loading'
}
```

Eu quero usar esse componente em outro lugar, e alterar o valor dessa props. Então eu utilizei do seguinte modo:

```
 <Loading loading='loading-inline' />
```

Só que o componente é renderizado da mesma forma, sem mudar o valor padrão.

Como faço para que o valor seja alterado?

Obrigada pela atenção.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não declarou o constructor e passou o props para a sua classe:

```
class Loading extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const loadingClasses = classNames({
      'loading': this.props.loading,
    })

    return (
      <div className={loadingClasses}>
        {this.props.loading === 'loading-inline' && <i className='fa fa-spinner fa-spin mr2' />}
        <FormattedMessage id='loading' />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Loading.propTypes = {
  loading: PropTypes.string,
}

Loading.defaultProps = {
  loading: 'loading'
}
```

Como seu componente não utiliza this.state, você pode criar um component funcional:

```
const Loading = ({ loading }) => { // desestruturação do objeto props
  const loadingClasses = classNames({
    'loading': loading,
  });

  return (
          <div className={loadingClasses}>
            {loading === 'loading-inline' && <i className='fa fa-spinner fa-spin mr2' />}
            <FormattedMessage id='loading' />
          </div>
  );
```